# What is the smartest way to make multiple dynamic storage queries using subxt?

Tags: rust, api, subxt

Is it possible to make batched storage calls to the runtime using `subxt` or is it only possible to make repeated individual calls against the state?

Say there are 3 storage variables I would like to query using `subxt`. I can do each of these individually:

```
let storage_addresses = vec![alice, bob, charlie]
    .iter()
    .map(|dest| subxt::dynamic::storage(
        "System",
        "Account",
        vec![
            // Something that encodes to an AccountId32 is what we need for the map key here:
            Value::from_bytes(&dest),
        ],
    )
);

let accounts = storage_addresses.iter().map(|a|
    api.storage()
        .fetch_or_default(&a, None)
        .await?
        .to_value()?
);
```

I'm curious if there is a smarter way to batch all these calls at once?

Comment: Have you tried using `batch` to batch the calls? [Here](https://github.com/paritytech/subxt/blob/8484c18624783af36476fc5bf6a0f08d5363a3db/examples/examples/dynamic_multisig.rs#L37-L75) is an example of using the dynamic api with `multisig` that may be helpful as it uses a nested inner call just like `batch` does.

Comment: Sorry for necroing. Regarding dynamic `batch` call: How would the `call` field be properly constructed? Say I have a `call: Vec<DynamicTxPayload>`, how would you derive the `Value`, e.g. `subxt::dynamic::tx("Utility", "batch", vec![("call", do_something_with_calls)]`?

Answer (score 3):

The options that I'm aware of are:

1. to do what you've done (whether you use static or dynamic storage lookups).
2. Use the "lower level" RPC method (`api.rpc().query_storage_at(..)` to query multiple entries at once (but you get bytes back and need to decode them manually), or
3. Use `api.storage().iter(some_address)` to iterate over *all* accounts (but you get nice types back here).